# Inject() function creating unwanted new instances in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I would just like to confirm that `inject()` provides different instances of a service and that this is the reason why my code is not working.

Take a good look at the following code:

```js
{
        path: 'recipes',
        component: RecipesComponent,
        resolve: {data: () => inject(HttpService).fetchRecipes()},
        children: [
           // a bunch of child routes 
        ]
},
```

Now, when we use `inject(HttpService)`, I would assume the instance is not global application-wide, or in other words, it's not in the root. Please take a look at Http Service.

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {
    constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService, private http: HttpClient, private authSerivce: AuthService) {}
    storeRecipes() {
        const recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipes()
        this.http.put('https://ng-recipe-shopping-f9c65-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/recipes.json', recipes)
        .subscribe(respone => {
            console.log(respone)
        })
    }

    ngOnInIt() {

    }

    fetchRecipes() {
        let authId: string
        this.authSerivce.userCred.subscribe(authToken => {
            authId = authToken
        })
      return  this.http.get<Recipe[]>(`https://ng-recipe-shopping-f9c65-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/recipes.json?auth=${authId}`)
        .pipe(map(recipes => {
            return recipes.map(recipe => {
                
                return {
                    ...recipe,
                    ingredients: recipe.ingredients ? recipe.ingredients : []
                }
            })
        }),
        tap(recipes => {
            this.recipeService.fetchRecipes(recipes)
        }))
    }
}
```

Now I would assume that when I am calling the `fetchRecipes()` method in the routing module that I am not calling `fetchRecipes()` on the root instance. I am stating this fact because the `userCred` subscription does not run even though I call `userCred.next(/* value */)` elsewhere in the application. In case for the reason why the subscription doesn't run is because there are different `HttpService` instances, then I would like to know how to solve it.

Keep in mind that I am relatively new to Angular, and I 60% understood the [Dependency Injection Context](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-context) from the official docs, but I still couldn't find what I was looking for.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you think that you are calling a separate instance, add a console log to the constructor that just says something like `new service instance!` and if you see it more than once, you are definitely creating more than 1 instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `Injectable` decorator with the `providedIn` property set to `'root'` in a class, then Angular will consider this class as a singleton, so it will only create and use a single instance of it.

`userCred` stream emission not being captured by the subscription has to be due to other issues.

Answer (score 0):

lets adjust your fetchRecipes function first.

```
fetchRecipes() {
    return this.authSerivce.userCred.pipe(
        switchMap(authToken => {
            return this.http.get<Recipe[]>(`https://ng-recipe-shopping-f9c65-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/recipes.json?auth=${authToken}`)
        }),
        map(recipes => {
           return recipes.map(recipe => {      
               return {
                   ...recipe,
                   ingredients: recipe.ingredients ? recipe.ingredients : []
               }
           })
       }),
       tap(recipes => {
           this.recipeService.fetchRecipes(recipes)
       }))
}
```

this way you will actually use the userCred token, now its a seperate subscription which will not work, based on what i can read from your code.